# After doing the partial upgrade everything have got changed

Tags: upgrade, partial-upgrade

The upgrade manager asked me to do a partial upgrade on Ubuntu 18.04. i did it via the graphical software updater tool. After that, once the system was rebooted, it shows Debian v10 with debian logo

[image]

More over, the file manager does not open(It opens for less than a second and then disappeares, the system wired connection as well as wifi connection are broken("Activation of network connection failed", it says), thus I don't have any Internet access on the system. Also some other 3rd party programs like Opera, VLC, ... aren't working, either.

I was wondering if there is any way which I can downgrade the system without losing my data?!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *partial upgrade* but please provide more detail on what you did (commands etc. as `do-release-upgrade` does not generally result in what you describe).  Yes it's possible to see mention of debian, even debian logos during upgrade, but provide more detail on what you mean by debian v10.  Third party sources are disabled by `do-release-upgrade` so that is normal, you can just re-activate them once you confirm those sources do support your new 18.04 (bionic).

Comment: @guiverc All I did was just following the software updater tool. As it asked me to do partial upgrader, so i accepted it. Here is the login page https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx4X7.jpg

Comment: What you are seeing there is only a background picture on a dm/greeter.  That is easily changed, and is possibly just caused by something that you'd installed long ago, but the update caused a display-manager change that caused that image to be used.  I'd expect you could remember what debian sourced material you have used that has put that on your system (that would not be found in Ubuntu repositories), but personally I wouldn't be worried by that (but I'd investigate your apt logs to find out why if it was my box).

Comment: @guiverc Thanks a lot for your response. I fixed the Internet connection by manual configuration, as it seems the DHCP is broken. After that once I entered `apt update`, I found the problem as it is fetching the data from Debian repository. So it seems it was a bug, as after the partial upgrade the repository was changed from Ubuntu to Debian.

Comment: I am not aware of anything in Ubuntu that would cause source repository information to change from Ubuntu to Debian.  The debian logo & name can occur [in pictures/images] because debian is upstream of Ubuntu because some 'universe' repository (community supported) software hasn't changed it; however this is not the case with 'main' Canonical/Ubuntu supported packages. You haven't said what you mean by *partial upgrade*, and as you describe sources change, I'd check your install as it doesn't sound reliable or secure.  What your describing shouldn't occur unless done by someone & not a bug.